# $(this).val() not working to get text from span using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Giving this html, i want to grab "August" from it when i click on it:

```
<span class="ui-datepicker-month">August</span>
```

i tried

```
$(".ui-datepicker-month").live("click", function () {
    var monthname =  $(this).val();
    alert(monthname);
});
```

but doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Instead of [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), like this:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-month").live("click", function () {
    var monthname =  $(this).text();
    alert(monthname);
});
```

Or in jQuery 1.7+ use `on()` as `live` is deprecated:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-month', function () {
    var monthname =  $(this).text();
    alert(monthname);
});
```

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for input type elements (including textareas and dropdowns), since you're dealing with an element with text content, use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) here.

Comment: NOTE: `.live()` is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9+

Comment: Both .html() and .text() worked for my span element.

Answer (score 23):

I think you want `.text()`:

```
var monthname = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 8):

To retrieve text of an auto generated span value just do this :

```
var al = $("#id-span-name").text();    
alert(al);
```

Answer (score 5):

-None of the above consistently worked for me. So here is the solution i worked out that works consistently across all browsers as it uses basic functionality. Hope this may help others. Using jQuery 8.2

1) Get the jquery object for "span". 
2) Get the DOM object from above. Using jquery .get(0)
3) Using DOM's object's innerText get the text.

Here is a simple example

```
var curSpan = $(this).parent().children(' span').get(0);
var spansText = curSpan.innerText;
```

HTML

```
<div >
<input type='checkbox' /><span >testinput</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.html()` to get content of `span` and or `div` elements.

example:

```
    var monthname =  $(this).html();
    alert(monthname);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here we go:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-month").click(function(){  
var  textSpan = $(this).text();
alert(textSpan);   
});
```

Hope it helps;)

Answer (score 2):

`.val()` is for input elements, use `.html()` instead