# Get values on nested spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing a tagging functionality to a website and need to get the value of the single tags (in this case "foo", "bar, "baz") with jQuery, for pushing into a database.
For any reasons I got stuck with this problem even it seems not to be that difficult…

Adding a tag via input field creates a new `<span class="tagval">` inside a `<span class="tag">` inside the `<div id="tags_tagsinput">`.

I need to get the value of the "tagval" spans but can´t manage it even with strong research on this topic.

Here's the HTML snippet:

```js
var tagValue = $(".tagval").html();
console.log("tagValue is:" + tagValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags_tagsinput" class="tagsinput">
  <span class="tag">
    <span class="tagval">foo</span>
    <span class="tagval">bar</span>
    <span class="tagval">baz</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

The only result I always got with .value or .text is an "undefined"…
Would be great to get your support on this :)

Comment: Just use `text()`. We need to see your code to tell you where your problem is, though

Comment: "Strong research" = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567835/get-text-from-span-using-jquery

Comment: Yeah thanks…

But even using the text() or html(), returns either a blank or an undefined when doing like this:

`var tagValue =  $(".tagval").html();
  console.log("tagValue is:" + tagValue);`

Comment: @bengraf did you put the code in an onload event handler like `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @bengraf what you've shown works, so long as you're running it when the DOM is ready, as you should be.

Comment: Thanks for your great support!
You´re totally right with the $(document).ready()…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need an onload handler and a each loop. It works like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tagval").each(function(){
    var tagValue = $(this).text();
    console.log("tagValue is:" + tagValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags_tagsinput" class="tagsinput">
  <span class="tag">
    <span class="tagval">foo</span>
    <span class="tagval">bar</span>
    <span class="tagval">baz</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Works so far! Thank´s a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here you can do with javascript/jquery

```
<script>
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.tagval');
    spans.forEach(function(span){
    console.log(span.innerText)
})
</script>
```

Comment: Remember that `querySelectorAll().forEach()` won't work in IE

Comment: There is zero jQuery in this answer. You should also make an attempt to format code properly, especially when posting answers for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.tag .tagval').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.tagval', function () {
    var spanVal=$(this).val()
    alert(spanVal);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Use `.text()` method to get the `text` inside `span` element.

```js
var spanval=$('.tagval').text();
console.log(spanval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags_tagsinput" class="tagsinput">
  <span class="tag">
    <span class="tagval">foo</span>
    <span class="tagval">bar</span>
    <span class="tagval">baz</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first example don't make much sense since it basically does what your second example do, only difference is that your first example, generates 3 empty variables.